# How to restore the IE6 or IE7 function that shows URL's when the cursor is on a hyperlink?

Tags: url, hyperlink

Before, when I used IE6 or IE7, whenever I would bring a cursor on a hyperlink its URL would always be shown down in the left corner of my screen right above the tray, but now it doesn't show URLs for some reason. I don't know why - perhaps, I accidentally clicked on some wrong button. How can I restore that function?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

View > Toolbars > Status Bar  (must be checked)

.